# Merge Cells in DevExpress VGridControl and Export to Excel

Tags: excel, merge, grid, devexpress-windows-ui

I want to do a simple merging of cells in a **`DevExpress`** **`VGridControl`**. The attached image shows exactly what I need. I have come across a lot of support tickets by DevExpress and all are redirected to just one link of ***`Devexpress Sample E3019`***.

Firstly this is a very complex process, but even if I use this to merge cells in my `VGridControl`, the cells are not merged in the excel file when exported.

I had posted this question in the `Devexpress` Support Forum but did not get a positive reply on the same : 
https://www.devexpress.com/support/center/Question/Details/T392883

(Please do not confuse the **`VGridControl`** with **`GridControl`** - they are two different functionalities used for different purposes)

The below image exactly shows what I want to achieve

[image: Merged cell view]

Comment: Hi Kinjal, welcome to SO. Consider show us the code you tried, and explain what non-expected (error?) results you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this functionality in place by first exporting the VGridControl to Excel and then reading the Excel file from C#. We can perform cell by cell operations and formatting using c# - refer the below link :

http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-format-excel.htm